# When to use self and when not to use self

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Which class option is preferable and why?

**Option 1**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def sayHello(self, name):
        print "{} says hello!".format(name)
    def driver(self):
        for name in names:        # names is generated in the driver function by some means of input
            self.sayHello(name)
```

**Option 2**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
    def sayHello(self):
        print "{} says hello!".format(self.name)
    def driver(self):
        for name in names:        # names is generated in the driver function by some means of input
            self.name = name
            self.sayHello()
```

You can assume that there are more variables than just `name` and that multiple functions are using these variables. The main point I am trying to make is that the variable value's are changing inside the `for` loop

Comment: Option 3. Definitely option 3. Neither of the two options you posted is good.

Comment: @Aran-Fey what are good options then?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you're even using a class. This is not how classes should be used. And I can't tell you how to do it properly because I don't know what "it" even is. I don't know what the point of your code is. My best guess is that `sayHello` and `driver` should be functions (not methods), and that there should be no class at all.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your exemple is syntaxically correct, it doesn't help at all understand your question regarding how to use a instance attribute.

From want I'm guessing, there's two questions :

- When to use a class method (`def foo(self, bar)`) ?
- When to use a instance attribute (`self.name`) ?

Instance attribute should be used when you need to "share" a variable between functions or retrieve it from outside a function. That variable will be "attached" to the object (for exemple, the color of a car, the nickname of a user, ...)

If your function / method need to call this kind of variable, it must use `self` to get it, so you have to set it as the first argument when defining this function.

If you just need a temporary variable to loop over it and do some stuff, you don't need to use a class method, a simple function will do the trick.

Comment: So I am using this both in a loop, but while looping I am passing this variable to several other methods, this is why I am asking if I should set this variable to `self.variable` and access `self.variable` in each of the methods I call, or if I should simply pass the `variable` to the method on each call. 
In your example of the color of a car, say I want to loop through multiple colors (red, green, blue) and at each color as the user if they like this color `isColorGood()` (note that I also want to have other methods. Should I set `self.color = color` for each iteration or simple pass color?

Comment: Both strategy may have a sense. There aren't an absolute response for it, but only common sense: does it make sense to loop and change the name of someone ? (surely no, there should not be any action that change a 100time the name of someone), but let say it's a book, and you have an object attribute "current_page", it might make sense to loop over it.

Comment: Going with the book analogy, does it make sense to do something like `self.current_page` and then in say a method called `read_page()` reference `self.current_page` or does it make sense to just say `read_page(current_page)`. I know it can be done either way, but I am asking what makes sense. I obviously understand that changing a Person's name 100 times is bad, but in the case of the pages does this referencing style change your design choice?

Comment: It depends. Are there other methods that need to know current page ? Do you need to save it ? `read_page(page)` is better than `read_page(current_page)`. The only thing that should make your choice good is if it answer the following question: does it make the code easier to read / understand / maintain.

Comment: I personally think that `self` makes things harder to read, since you have to start tracking down what can set/alter the value, while passing something into a method as a parameter is clear what the value is and who has access to it.

Comment: You're right. But if you need to use the variable outside the class (like `public` in Java) you don't have a choice, and if you need to store the variable for other methods (like `private` in Java), you don't have a choice either. If you only need the variable in one method, don't use `self`.